# Windows security event log showing lot of firewall rule changed alert

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-event-log

n my server i am getting lot of event id 4946. A change has been made to Windows Firewall exception list. A rule was added. i am getting this alert every day. can you help me to reslove this.

Regards,
KArthick V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely there are some Firewall rules defined via GPO. Everytime these GPOs are processed, the firewall rules are applied, resulting into the [4946](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364355(v=ws.10).aspx) event in the Event Log.

In addition, the message of the event should include the names of the rules that have been added. Knowing the rules, it might be easier to trace what/why are adding them.